# update the last entered value from a selection of values in a database with python , mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

Okay so i have a table which has student id and the student id is used as identifier to edit the column but what if the same student lends a book twice then all the student value will b edited which i don't want....i want the last entered data of student id to b edited and using a Sl.No is not a solution here because its practically complicated.I am using python connector. Please help :) Thanks in advance

code i use right now :

```
con = mysql.connect(host='localhosT', user='root',
                    password='*****', database='DB')
c = con.cursor()
c.execute(
    f"UPDATE library set `status`='Returned',`date returned`='{str(cal.selection_get())}' WHERE `STUDENT ID`='{e_sch.get()}';")
c.execute('commit')
con.close()
messagebox.showinfo(
    'Success', 'Book has been returned successfully')
```

Comment: How can we tell which row is the *last entered*? You need a column to define the ordering of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you want to update just one record that matches the `where` condition. For this to be done in a reliable manner, you need a column to define the ordering of the records. It could be a date, an incrementing id, or else. I assume that such column exists in your table and is called `ordering_column`.

A simple option is to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in the `UPDATE` statement, like so:

```
sql = """
    UPDATE library 
    SET status = 'Returned', date returned = %s 
    WHERE student_id = %s
    ORDER BY ordering_column DESC
    LIMIT 1
"""
c = con.cursor()
c.execute(sql, (str(cal.selection_get()), e_sch.get(), )
```

Note that I modified your code so input values are given as parameters rather than concatenated into the query string. This is an important change, that makes your code safer and more efficient.

Comment: i do have a sl.no tht has auto_increment so can i use tht? , like the id with the greatest sl.no shud only b edited

Comment: @CoolCloud: just replace `ordering_column` with the correct column for your table.

Comment: @CoolCloud: this is the part of the query that selects the "latest" record that satisfies the conditions.